# VB.NET Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer is not defined

Tags: vb.net, reference

I have a VB.NET application that I am trying to get working on our new system. (We have upgraded from Windows server 2003 to 2012) and I have a piece of software that I am unable to fix.

It uses a `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer` for some reason and it won't run because it is not defined.

I checked the reference and it looked like the path was pointing to a file that didn't exist.

I found a download for VS 2010 which is supposed to install the Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer but it hasn't worked.

If I copy the error exactly this is what it gives me:

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30002 Type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer' is not defined.    project C:\DATA\svn\project\trunk\project\frmMain.Designer.vb   195 Active`

I'm running VS Express 2015

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 8):

Visual studio > File menu > Tools > Nuget Package manager > Manage Nuget packages for Solution:

[image: screenshot1]

Then browse "Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms" and install it:

[image: screenshot2]

Then press F5 to "start debugging" , and you find  error fix.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue on one of my projects.  The solution I found was in `Solution Explorer`, Right Click `References` remove the flagged reference to `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer` then right click `References` and re-add `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms` (can be found by typing `winforms` in the search bar)

This immediately cleared up the Error for me. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll have a go later this week... I've forgotten what this was for lol

Comment: Helped to make an old project compile on VS 2015 / Win 10